# AWS DocumentDB length of password greater than maximum, but shouldn't be

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager, aws-documentdb

I'm setting up an AWS DocumentDB cluster using CloudFormation. I set up a password in Secrets Manager like this:

```yaml
  DbClusterCredentials:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: …
      Description: …
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "admin"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
        PasswordLength: 100
        ExcludeCharacters: '/"@'
```

Then I reference that in my cluster:

```yaml
  DbCluster:
    Type: AWS::DocDB::DBCluster
    Properties: 
      DBClusterIdentifier: …
      DBSubnetGroupName: …
      …
      MasterUsername: !Sub "{{resolve:${DbClusterCredentials}:SecretString:username}}"
      MasterUserPassword: !Sub "{{resolve:${DbClusterCredentials}:SecretString:password}}"
      …
```

When I try to deploy this with CloudFormation it rolls back with `CREATE_FAILED` for `DbCluster`, saying:

> Property validation failure: [Length of value for property {/MasterUserPassword} is greater than maximum allowed length {100}, Length of value for property {/MasterUsername} is greater than maximum allowed length {63}]

Um, but I requested a password of exactly 100 characters (which is not greater than the maximum of 100 characters), and the username should be `admin` (which is not greater than the maximum allowed length of 63). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe the syntax is: `'{{resolve:service-name:reference-key}}'` per the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html and I see examples online that use that syntax, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662283/can-i-force-cloudformation-to-resolve-values-from-secrets-manager So your code should be changed to: `"{{resolve:secretsmanager:${DbClusterCredentials}:SecretString:password}}"`

Comment: @MarkB I think that's it! Thank you very much! However there's more to the story; I'll describe everything in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarkB graciously pointed out, I had a typo in my code. The correct format is `{{resolve:secretsmanager:…`. I was missing `secretsmanager:`.

But then why was it giving me an error that the username and password were too long? Well that's the "interesting" part. It seems there was/is a [bug](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/94) where CloudFormation would validate the length of the reference rather than the dereferenced value. So since CloudFormation didn't recognize the reference name (even though the outer reference form `{{…}}` was correct), it decided, "oh, what the heck, since I don't know how to dereference that reference I'll just validate the reference itself". As this substitution interpolated the secret ARN, the full reference was something like this:

`{{resolve:arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-:xxxxxxxxxxxx:secret:this-is-my-secret-name-xxxxxx:SecretString:password}}`

That's over 100 characters.

So I fixed the reference:

```yaml
      …
      MasterUsername: !Sub "{{resolve:secretsmanager:${DbClusterCredentials}:SecretString:username}}"
      MasterUserPassword: !Sub "{{resolve:secretsmanager:${DbClusterCredentials}:SecretString:password}}"
      …
```

And … I get another error because the password is over 99 characters. But why? Well even though [`AWS::DocDB::DBCluster`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-docdb-dbcluster.html) says that `MasterUserPassword` "Must contain from 8 to 100 characters", apparently DocumentDB interfaces with RDS in some manner, and RDS has a limitation of 99 characters for the password. (At least that's what the error message said.)

And finally the username can't be `admin` for DocumentDB.

Whew! Fixing the typo, changing the password length to 99, and switching to another username finally got this working.